# CORS support in NodeJS not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, google-chrome, cors

I'm using CORS in nodejs script as:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

I'm using an AJAX request to fetch JSON data from another domain.

This works fine for all browsers namely, Mozilla Firefox and Safari. However, it does not work in case of Google Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
   next();
});
```

OR

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());

// ## CORS middleware
// 
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```